# Connecting to google drive from python in a github action

Tags: python, github, google-oauth, pydrive

I'm trying to create a github action that runs a python script that has access to google drive. I use OIDC to auth to google drive in the github action, but I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure out how to connect to google in the python file. I'm using pydrive2.

Clearly I'm going about the python authentication to google piece incorrectly, but how? My expectation is that the file created by github OIDC would properly create credentials file that could be directly used to authenticate.

My github action looks like this:

```
name: 'Test Auth'
on: [workflow_dispatch, push]

jobs:
  ExploreActions:
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
      
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # actions/checkout MUST come before auth
    - uses: 'actions/checkout@v3'
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.ref }}
    - name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/###############/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider'
        service_account: '<user>@<service>.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
        create_credentials_file: true
    - name: Install Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with: 
        python-version: '3.11'
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: pip install pydrive2
      shell: bash
    - name: Test python
      run: python experimental/test_action.py
      shell: bash
```

My python file is simple:

```
from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive2.drive import GoogleDrive
import os 

creds = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
print(creds)

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(creds)
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

When the action runs, I get the following output (editted for clarity):

```
2023-06-13T19:52:03.2759862Z Requested labels: ubuntu-latest
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2353436Z ##[group]Run google-github-actions/auth@v1
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2353828Z with:
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2354261Z   workload_identity_provider: projects/########/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2354906Z   service_account: xxxxxxxxx
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2355322Z   create_credentials_file: true
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2355641Z   export_environment_variables: true
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2355973Z   cleanup_credentials: true
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2356231Z   access_token_lifetime: 3600s
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2356660Z   access_token_scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2357018Z   retries: 3
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2357239Z   backoff: 250
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2357534Z   id_token_include_email: false
2023-06-13T19:52:14.2357818Z ##[endgroup]
2023-06-13T19:52:14.4899340Z Created credentials file at "/home/runner/work/small_projects/small_projects/gha-creds-e6ba77a2da78ef5b.json"
2023-06-13T19:52:14.5123821Z ##[group]Run actions/setup-python@v4
2023-06-13T19:52:23.2009265Z   pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64
2023-06-13T19:52:23.2009636Z   PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/pkgconfig
2023-06-13T19:52:23.2010012Z   Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64
2023-06-13T19:52:23.2010370Z   Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64
2023-06-13T19:52:23.2010724Z   Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64
2023-06-13T19:52:23.2011067Z   LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib
2023-06-13T19:52:23.2011362Z ##[endgroup]
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6651848Z /home/runner/work/small_projects/small_projects/gha-creds-e6ba77a2da78ef5b.json
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6654092Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6665200Z   File "/home/runner/work/small_projects/small_projects/experimental/test_action.py", line 9, in <module>
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6668147Z     gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(creds)
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6670573Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydrive2/auth.py", line 418, in LoadCredentialsFile
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6673662Z     self.credentials = self._default_storage.get()
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6675655Z                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6677537Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 407, in get
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6680768Z     return self.locked_get()
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6688395Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6690735Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oauth2client/file.py", line 54, in locked_get
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6693956Z     credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(content)
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6696512Z                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6698658Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 302, in new_from_json
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6702354Z     module_name = data['_module']
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6704914Z                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-06-13T19:52:23.6706966Z KeyError: '_module'
2023-06-13T19:52:23.7152157Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

########################### Edit

With the suggestion from @Saxtheowl, I changed the python file to auth using the google auth apis and got it to work.  A note that I had to actually share a file in google drive with my service user in order to get any files to show up:

```
import os 
import google.auth
import googleapiclient.discovery

creds, project = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'])
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute() 
items = results.get('files', [])
print(items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the credentials file created by GitHub doesn't match the format that `PyDrive2` expects.

You could try Google's `google-auth` library

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.environ.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"),
    # Add the scope you need to access
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

Now you should have a authenticated Drive service you can use to interact with Google Drive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I tried your suggestion out and am getting a different error.... 

File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.3/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 52, in from_dict
    raise exceptions.MalformedError(
google.auth.exceptions.MalformedError: Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_email, token_uri.

Comment: See my edits above... I was able to get it to work, with some slight changes from what you have above.  Thank you!